# How to get a div to scroll vertically and reveal gradient

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, linear-gradients

I'm trying to get three divs side-by-side horizontally. I want the left-most div to scroll, so the gradient reveals itself as the user scrolls. For some reason the divs aren't adjacent and the left one isn't scrolling, and I don't know why.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%}

.overall {
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  width: 10%;
  height: 200%;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.one {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.two {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="overall">
  <div class="scroll"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clarification: I want the divs to be adjacent horizontally, so their total width adds to 100%. But I also want the gradient div to scroll vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not placed *horizontally* because `div`'s are *block-level elements* by *default*, meaning they occupy the entire *row* / *width* of the screen.

Nowadays typically, if one needs to place them horizontally, he/she does it with the ***Flexbox*** or `display: flex` set on the *parent element*. Of course there are also other ways of doing it.

And for the *scrolling*, it doesn't *scroll* because there's nothing to *scroll*. Put some *"tall"* enough *content* (which is greater than the set `height` of `200%`) inside the `.scroll` `div` and see it in *"action"*:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%}

.overall {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline by default */
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  /*width: 10%;*/
  flex: 1; /* flexbox way of defining width */
  height: 200%; /* necessary ? */
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  overflow-y: auto; /* modified, only shows the scrollbar when needed */
}

.one {
  /*width: 70%;*/
  flex: 7;
  /*height: 100%; not necessary, takes the parents height */
  background: lightgreen;
}

.two {
  /*width: 20%;*/
  flex: 2;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="overall">
  <div class="scroll">
    <p style="height: 250%">Some looooong paragraph which is taller that its parent...just for demo...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```